# remove the url, date,page no while taking print

Tags: javascript

i have content inside the div , div id print_my_content,

i want to print content inside the print_my_content DIV,

And i dont want to print the URL, Date, Page no ,

my present script printing these and all,

And also printer device is the DOT MATRIX PRINTER, and paper is voucher (size is 550 width 550 height,

So my content should set inside these height and width also,

Tell some suggestion ,

```
var prtContent = document.getElementById(strid);
var WinPrint =
window.open('','','left=0,top=0');
WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
alert(prtContent.innerHTML);
WinPrint.document.close();
WinPrint.focus();
WinPrint.print();
WinPrint.close();
prtContent.innerHTML=strOldOne;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use CSS.

Your normal css file will leave the elements (divs, spans, whatever) visible, but your "@media print" file will set them to "display:none".