# how to hide the url comes while printing the page using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to hide the url comes while printing the page using javascript or jquery

```
 .nonPrintable{display:none !important;}
 .hide { visibility: hidden }
```

Comment: [hide url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359643/remove-the-url-date-page-no-while-taking-print) this might be of help

Comment: what url anchor tags?

Comment: the url comes on page after printing it that url i have to hide

Comment: You mean the URL and date and stuff *your browser* adds? I don’t think you can hide that; it’s the user’s choice to disable it.

Comment: but requirement is that url should not come we have to do it by coding

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It's a local browser setting available only to the user.

Comment: but requirement is that url should not come we have to do it by coding

Comment: Your business requirements do not change the way the browser works.